# If twice-differiantiable $f$ satisfies $f(x)f''(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function such that$$f(x)f''(x)=0.\quad \forall x \in \mathbb R$$Then is it true that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1$? I could not find any other function satisfying the condition, but could not prove that there are no other functions. Please help.

Comment: Take a point where $f(x)\neq0$. Since $f$ is continuous it is non-zero on a neighborhood of that point. Therefore $f''$ is zero on that interval. Therefore $f$ is linear on that interval. That solution extends to the connected component of the complement of the set where $f$ vanishes. The connected component is an interval. If the connected component has a boundary the function wouldn't be differentiable unless it is constant equal to zero. Therefore, it is either constant equal to zero, or there is no boundary and it is equal to the line we computed before.

Comment: You can prove by noting that this implies either $f(x) = 0$ (so is a 0 order polynomial) or $f''(x) = 0 \implies f'(x) = a \implies f(x) = ax + b$.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Your suggestion is very imprecise.

Comment: @OsamaGhani : you are in a sense claiming either that $(\forall x(P\lor Q) )\implies (\forall x P\lor \forall x Q)$, or that "for all $x$, if $f''(x) =0$, then $f(x) = ax+b$", both of which are false statements. I suggest the OP look at Bettybel's comment rather

Comment: @Bettybel: Why don't you post your answer as an answer, so that it can be accepted by the OP? As it stands no decent person would post another answer, hence the question remains in limbo. As a result it will be bumped back to the main board every month or so for years to come.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter That conclusion follows from your assumptions if there are only decent people.

Comment: @Bettybel By "decent person" I think is meant someone who wouldn't claim an answer that is given in a comment.

Comment: Given that the question was answered completely in a comment almost a year ago, you should really explain what you find unsatisfying about that comment before offering a bounty.

Comment: @EricWofsey: That answer is not really written in a rigorous way ...

Comment: Ladies, Gentlemen, please!  Bettybel's answer, if not completely rigorous, seems to me upon casual inspection that it could be made so without too much effort.  If Bettybel doesn't want to write it up as an answer, then I would encourage someone who *does* to do so; otherwise we run into the old "answering questions in comments" boogey-man.  In sooth, I was working up an answer a lot like her comment until I got sucked into this fracas.  Let those who wish to answer do so, giving credit where it is due.  OK, I'll shut up now!

Comment: Now let's see what happens . . . ;)

Comment: Side comment: $C^2$ is not the same thing as twice differentiable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach which does not involve extending intervals on which $f$ does not vanish.

Suppose there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f''(x_0) ≠ 0$. Without loss of generality, assume that $f''(x_0) > 0$. Since $f(x_0) f''(x_0) = 0$, then $f(x_0) = 0$. If there exists $δ > 0$ such that $f(x) ≠ 0$ for any $x \in (x_0, x_0 + δ)$, then$$
f(x) f''(x) = 0 \Longrightarrow f''(x) = 0, \quad \forall x \in (x_0, x_0 + δ)
$$
which is contradictory to the fact that $f''(x_0) ≠ 0$ and [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). Therefore, there exists $\{x_n\} \subseteq (x_0, x_0 + δ)$ such that $x_n → x_0\ (n → ∞)$ and $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n \geqslant 1$, which implies $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Now, because $f''(x_0) > 0$, there exists $δ_0 > 0$ such that $f'(x) > f'(x_0) = 0$ for any $x \in (x_0, x_0 + δ_0)$, which implies $f$ is strictly increasing on $[x_0, x_0 + δ_0]$. Therefore,$$
f(x) > f(x_0) = 0,\ f(x) f''(x) = 0 \Longrightarrow f''(x) = 0, \quad \forall x \in (x_0, x_0 + δ_0]
$$
which again leads to contradiction by Darboux's theorem.

Hence, $f''(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which implies $f(x)$ is a polynomial of $x$ with degree no greater than $1$.

Comment: Now that looks great ...

Comment: This isn't my post, but can someone clarify to me what the contradiction implied by Darboux's theorem is? I know the statement of the theorem but I can't understand how it plays into this

Comment: @Hushus46 By Darboux's theorem, there should exist an $x\in\left(x_0,x_0+\dfrac δ2\right)$ such that $f''(x)=\dfrac{f''(x_0)}2\in(0,f''(x_0))$, a contradiction.

Comment: You might be interested in my answer, posted today.

Answer (score 3):

$(f^2)''=2(f')^2\geq 0$ so that $f^2$ is convex.

If $f^2(a)=f^2(b)=0$ for $a\neq b$, then consider the following type (Others are similar) :

$f^2|[a,b]=0$ and $f^2|\mathbb{R}^2-[a,b]>0$

Here by an assumption $f''|\mathbb{R}^2-[a,b]=0$. so that $f$ is linear on $\mathbb{R}^2-[a,b]$

And $f=0$ on $[a,b]$

Comment: I don't understand what happens after you write $f(a)^2=f(b)^2=0$ for $a\ne b$  ...

Comment: A convex non-constant  $C^2$ function may have more than three zeros. Example: $f(x)=x^4$ for $x<0$, $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I add more explantion.

Comment: This approach, which has proved the simplest case, actually involves discussion similar to that in the proof of @Bettybel if it is pursued rigorously. So this answer hides a lot of technical details in fact.

Comment: @ Alex Francisco : I agree to your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on [@BettyBel's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349772/if-f-in-c2-mathbb-r-satisfies-fxfx-0-for-all-x-in-mathbb-r-then#comment4839900_2349772) (who
unfortunately did not come back to post an answer):

$$
 A = \{ x \in \Bbb R \mid f(x) \ne 0 \} \, .
$$
is an open set. If $A$ is empty or $A = \Bbb R$ then we are done.
Otherwise the connected components of $A$ are (bounded or unbounded)
open intervals of the form
$$
  (-\infty, a) \quad \text{or} \quad (b, \infty) \quad\text{or}\quad (a, b) \, .
$$

Now it is easy so see that the last case can not occur: 
If $I = (a, b)$ is a connected component of $A$ then $f$ is linear on $I$ with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$,
contradicting that $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in I$.

Therefore
$$
 A = (-\infty, a) \cup (b, \infty)
$$
for some $a \le b$, and $f$ is linear on each of the intervals
$$
 (-\infty, a] \, , \, [a, b] \, , \, [b, \infty) \, .
$$

Since $f$ is differentiable the slope must be the same on each
interval, i.e. $f$ is linear on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I overlooked when editing.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to prove that $f'' \equiv 0$. Here, we only assume that $f$ is twice-differentiable but not a-priori known to be $C^2$.

---

Let $I = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \}$. We immediately check that

> 1. If $f''(x) \neq 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ and hence $x \in I$.
> 2. If $x$ is an interior point of $I$, then $f \equiv 0$ near $x$ and hence $f''(x) = 0$.

This tells that $f''(x) \neq 0$ is possible only for $x \in \partial I$. Now we claim that $\partial I$ has at most 2 points. Once this is proved, a simple argument (Lemma 2 applied to $g = f'$) shows that $f''$ is identically zero.

**Lemma 1.** $\partial I$ has at most 2 elements.

*Proof.* If $a < b$ are in $I$, then $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)f'(x) = f'(x)^2$ tells that

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f'(x)^2 \, dx = \left[ f(x)f'(x) \right]_{a}^{b} = 0. $$

Since $f'$ is continuous, $f' \equiv 0$ on $[a, b]$ and hence $f$ is constant on $[a, b]$ with value $f(a) = 0$. So $[a, b] \subseteq I$. This implies that $I$ is connected. Since $I$ is closed, it is either empty, singleton or closed interval. The claim is true in any cases. ////

**Lemma 2.** If $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $g'(x) \to \ell$ as $x \to a$, then $g'(a) = \ell$.

*Proof.* By the mean value theorem, for each $x \neq a$, there exists $\xi = \xi(x)$ between $x$ and $a$ such that $g(x) - g(a) = g'(\xi)(x - a)$. Since $\xi(x) \to a$ as $x\to a$, it follows that

$$ g'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a} g'(\xi(x)) = \ell. $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in \mathbb R.$ Suppose $f''(a)\ne 0.$ Because $f''$ is continuous, $f''(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$ in an open interval $I$ containing $a.$ The given condition then implies $f=0$ in $I.$ But if $f=0$ on $I,$ then $f''=0$ on $I,$ contradiction. Therefore $f''(a)=0.$  Since $a\in \mathbb R$ was arbitrary, $f''=0$ everywhere in $\mathbb R.$ This implies $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $1.$

Comment: Unfortunately, the condition $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ was added to the title by a third party, the original question only stated that $f$ is twice differentiable. (That change has been reverted now.)